Quantifying (observed) spatial clustering?
I am looking for some advice regarding spatial statistics.
I have a large dataset with multiple samples across 5 different conditions. Each sample is composed of different point types in 2D space. For example:
Sample 1, Condition 1:
X, Y, type
1, 1, A
5, 3, A
11, 2, B
6, 22, L
...

We have noticed that for some conditions, some point types (let's call them A and B, red and blue respectively) display different distribution. In most cases ('usual pattern'), type A clusters with other A-type points and type B clusters with other Bs; the clusters of each type are visually distinct from one another (see image, right subplot, 'usual pattern'). However, under certain conditions, we noticed that clusters of A and B are more admixed with one another; it probably still holds that As cluster with As (more than with Bs), but the clusters of As and Bs are clustered/merged together (see image, left subplot, 'observed pattern').
What is the best approach to capture and quantify this observed phenomenon? (Full dislosure: I am new to spatial statistics).

So far, we have looked into Shannon's entropy (across all point types, say A-M) between different conditions, to check whether there is more heterogeneity in point type distribution across the conditions of interest (but there does not seem to be a significant difference). We have also investigated measures of centrality, as well as neighbourhood enrichment (we have performed these for all point types, i.e. A-M). Most recently, we resorted to trying DBSCAN (focusing only on point types A and B), in the hope that we may be able to demonstrate that there is a difference in resultant cluster sizes (although personally, I am not convinced whether this is the right approach to the problem). It is possible that we have not tuned the model parameters satisfactorily yet, but so far it does not seem to capture the problem. I am also concerned that, whilst it may be helpful for exploratory data analysis, it is unlikely that we will be able to use DBSCAN outputs to meaningfully compare between the results different conditions.
Intuitively, I think that the answer probably lies in network analysis and looking into clustering behaviour a few nodes away (rather than perhaps only the immediate neighbours, which is probably why the neighborhood enrichment analysis did not work for us).
What is the best approach to demonstrate and quantify the observed clustering phenomenon? Ideally, we would need an approach that allows to compare between the different conditions.

Just a ahort answer from my phone: You should definitely look into the area of spatial point pattern analysis. It has a large array of methods to analyse this type of data ranging from exploratory tools over non-parametric tests to full parametric modelling with accompanying statistical theory. I recommend the book Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R (https://book.spatstat.org), but as a co-author I'm of course biased. Unfortunately there isn't free online access to the whole book, but you can take a look at the free sample chapter 7, which covers some of the methods that would be natural to use.

Thank you so much! That pointed me in the right direction! (sorry for the delay in my reply - I thought that I did not have sufficient reputation to comment...)
